# MySqli query works in phpmyadmin, not works in php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a problem.

I try to do simple query:

```
        $this->db->query("  INSERT INTO prognosis(stamp,day_ep,day_ep_sum,day_time,day_time_sum,week_ep,week_ep_sum,week_time,week_time_sum,month_ep,month_ep_sum,month_time,month_ep_sum,year_ep,year_ep_sum,year_time,year_time_sum)
                        VALUES('$stamp',$today_ep,$today_ep_sum,$today_time,$today_time_sum,$week_ep,$week_ep_sum,$week_time,$week_time_sum,$month_ep,$month_ep_sum,$month_time,$month_time_sum,$year_ep,$year_ep_sum,$year_time,$year_time_sum)
                    ");
```

... and table is still empty, so I print full query with values to html file (meta charset = utf-8) using echo:

```
INSERT INTO prognosis ( stamp, day_ep, day_ep_sum, day_time, day_time_sum, week_ep, week_ep_sum, week_time, week_time_sum, month_ep, month_ep_sum, month_time, month_time_sum, year_ep, year_ep_sum, year_time, year_time_sum ) VALUES ( '2016-01-09', 7, 5544, 318, 210948, 53, 5547, 2240, 211040, 289, 5744, 12844, 219835, 3366, 8822, 151232, 358223 )
```

ctrl+C, ctrl+V to phpmyadmin, and table accept that query(why?)

DESCRIBE:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Field] => id
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => NO
        [Key] => PRI
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => auto_increment
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Field] => stamp
        [Type] => date
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Field] => day_ep
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Field] => day_ep_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Field] => day_time
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Field] => day_time_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [Field] => week_ep
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [Field] => week_ep_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [Field] => week_time
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [Field] => week_time_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [Field] => month_ep
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [Field] => month_ep_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [Field] => month_time
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [Field] => month_time_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [Field] => year_ep
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [Field] => year_ep_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [Field] => year_time
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [Field] => year_time_sum
        [Type] => int(11)
        [Null] => YES
        [Key] => 
        [Default] => 
        [Extra] => 
    )
```

)

I noticed interesting thing:
When I try to find reason of that behavior, I try to execute shorter query:

```
        $this->db->query("  INSERT INTO prognosis(stamp,year_ep,year_ep_sum,year_time,year_time_sum)
                        VALUES('$stamp',$year_ep,$year_ep_sum,$year_time,$year_time_sum)
```

and It works fine but I have to execute full version of query.

Comment: You have month_ep_sum twice - second one in place of $month_time_sum

Comment: Thanks, probably that was the problem, but finally I reorganized the table. Now column names looks like: Id, stamp, `key`,`value`, and each param is in other row.

Comment: Glad all is good. Delete the post if it is not applicable anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Please Check Collaction Field in phpmyadmin and if any selected then set blank.